# Passing A Component Prop into a Higher Order Component using React

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm using a React drag and drop library called react-dnd.
To create a drop target, higher level component wrappers are used.

Example:

```
export default DropTarget('myDragType', squareTarget, collect)(Dropzone);
```

Now instead of 'myDragType' I would like to pass a prop or something similar so that I don't have to make a new component for every drop type.

```
<Dropzone dragType="myDragType1" />
<Dropzone dragType="myDragType2" />
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I haven't fully thought this through, but I think either of the following might work: a) write another higher order component
b) write a stateless component (function) to return what you want
I'm unsure of the perf implications.